# Was Jediism shown to be a religion in Episodes I-VI?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

[image: Chirrut] 
<sup>[[Image Source]](https://www.inverse.com/article/20337-rogue-one-chirrut-mwe-photos-jyn-erso-jedha-death-star-mission)</sup>

[**Star Wars: Rogue One**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/) introduced the character [**Chirrut Imwe**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chirrut_%C3%8Emwe) who is described as:

> a spiritual warrior-monk

He and his friend [**Baze Malbus**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Baze_Malbus) were guardians of a Jedi temple on [**Jedha**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedha):

> a world of worship for those who believed in the Force, and a holy
>   site for pilgrims who sought spiritual guidance

A couple of times we hear Chirrut chant something that's sounds like a prayer,

> ***I am with the Force and the Force is with me***

e.g. when they are imprisoned by Saw Gerrera. Baze jokes that Chirrut is praying for the cell door to just open, to which he replies that Baze was once the most devoted guardian of them all and knows that it's possible.

But the Force isn't something magical (cough ... **[Midi-chlorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian)** ... cough), although that knowledge may not be universially known.

Watching the previous movies I didn't get the impression that the Jedi and the Force were considered "holy" or that they were worshipped in such a "religous" way (e.g. prayers and pilgrimages), but it's been a while since I watched those movies and it's totally possible I missed certain references.

**My Question:**

- Have the previous movies shown people praying to the Force and worshipping the Jedi as "holy" figures?

Comment: Jedi aren't considered "holy" as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DVK - It's pure assumption on my part, based on the Wiki quote using the word "holy" and seeing a giant statue of someone that looks like a Jedi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least in episode 4 we get the impression that OTHERS thought of it as a religion.

> VADER
>
> Don't be too proud of this 
>                       technological terror you have created.
>                       The ability to destroy a planet, or whole
>                       system is insignificant next to the power of the
>                       Force.
>
> MOTTI
>
> Don't try to frighten us with your 
>                       sorcerer's ways, Lord Vader.  Your sad 
>                       devotion to that ancient religion has not 
>                       helped you conjure up those stolen data 
>                       tapes... or given you clairvoyance enough 
>                       to find the rebel's hidden fortress.  I have
>                       to laugh .. ah ...
>
> Suddenly Motti chokes and starts to turn blue under Vader's spell.
>
> VADER
>
> I find your lack of faith disturbing.
>
> TARKIN
>
> Enough of this!

[script](http://whills.nu/4/sw7.html)

Watching episode 1-3 the Jedi do at least have a mystical element to them, and they themselves meditate alot. But other then the "prayers" in Rogue One as far as I remember we never see any overt or "traditional" practicing of a religion. At most hero worship, and fear by those fighting a Jedi.

Answer (score 4):

A slight correction which may provide insight towards an answer;

The temple Chirrut and Beze protect was not a *Jedi Temple*, it was a **Kyber Temple.**

These were force attuned artifacts that the Jedi believed to '[border on sentience](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)', and as such were revered by both Jedi and Sith alike.

Baze and Chirrut were guardians of the temple, but clearly the depiction of Baze as an agnostic or even atheist would seek to demonstrate that to acquire this profession, one does not necessarily even have to believe in the spirituality of Kyber crystals. It would seem that whilst Chirrut is a monastic figure who sees his role as an vocation, Baze saw it simply as an occupation.

Whilst Chirrut's belief in the force would be similar to a Museum guardsman being an active historian, it does not necessitate a worship of the Jedi; merely a belief in the power of the force. A belief shared by the Jedi.

Comment: Actually I think Cassian descibes the duo as "former Guardians of the Whills" who are now out of work. They are not Jedi, but it *is* a religious order, but you are correct: it is not a Jedi Temple

Comment: Yes, now I kinda remember Cassian saying something like "protectors of the Kyber temple". However, I'm pretty sure Chirrut said that Baze was once "the most devoted of them all".